# Device simulations in firefox browser

Tags: firefox, emulation

We have device emulations in chrome ( developer tools > show drawer > Emulation ).

Where can I find the same in Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense for a browser vendor to have a device emulator if they actually sell a device of their own that moreover uses their rendering engine.

Since there is such a think as Firefox OS I think this is as close as you will get:

[Firefox OS 1.1 Simulator Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/)

A dedicated page for the OS Emulator:

[Firefox OS Emulator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator)